# Conditionally replace NAs in Certain Columns Based on Row Values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na

For a dataframe like I have below, I am trying to selectively replace the `NA`s in columns `a`, `b`, and `c` with a 0 using R, but only when there is at least one missing value in those columns for that row.

For example, I would want to replace the `NA`s in rows 1,2, and 5, but leave row 4 alone, and not replace the `NA` in column `d`

*sample data*

```
 df <- data.frame(a = c(1,NA,2,NA,3,4), 
                  b = c(NA,5,6,NA,7,8), 
                  c = c(9,NA,10,NA,NA,11),
                  d = c("Alpha","Beta","Charlie","Delta",NA,"Foxtrot"))

> df
   a  b  c       d
1  1 NA  9   Alpha
2 NA  5 NA    Beta
3  2  6 10 Charlie
4 NA NA NA   Delta
5  3  7 NA    <NA>
6  4  8 11 Foxtrot
```

*Desired outcome*

```
> df_naReplaced
   a  b  c       d
1  1  0  9   Alpha
2  0  5  0    Beta
3  2  6 10 Charlie
4 NA NA NA   Delta
5  3  7  0    <NA>
6  4  8 11 Foxtrot
```

The solutions that I have found so far only work on conditions by column, but not by row, or would require actively removing those columns from their context (in this example separating it from d).

I have tried using `ifelse` and an `if` statement like below but was unable to get it to work as selectively as I would like, as it replaces all `NA` in that column.

```
if(df %>% select(a:c) %>% any(!is.na(.))){
  df<- df %>% replace_na(list(a= 0,
                              b= 0,
                              c= 0)
)
}
```

Thank you for whatever help you are able to offer!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an R base solution

```
> df[,-4][(is.na(df[, -4]) & rowSums(is.na(df[, -4])) < 3)] <- 0
> df
   a  b  c       d
1  1  0  9   Alpha
2  0  5  0    Beta
3  2  6 10 Charlie
4 NA NA NA   Delta
5  3  7  0    <NA>
6  4  8 11 Foxtrot
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. I assume that replacing "-4" with c(1,2,3) would also work? The original data frame is much larger, so explicitly calling the appropriate columns is much simpler (on the order of selecting 7 columns instead of  700 columns).

Comment: @BPL exactly, you can select just the columns you want by indexing them